# call akka scheduler.scheduleOnce in actor did not work

Tags: akka

I want to use akka system's scheduler to do some thing interval

```
system.scheduler.scheduleOnce(interval.milliseconds, dayActor, DaySwitch)
```

I works fine, dayActor will receive DaySwitch message.

in dayActor

```
def receive = {
  case DaySwitch =>
    log.info("begin day switch")
    context.system.scheduler.scheduleOnce(1.day, self, DaySwitch)
```

after one day, the dayActor didn't receive DaySwitch message.

How to fix it. Thanks!

Comment: You need to provide more information on failure

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that you have troubles with starting of scheduler or in place which serve interaction with `receive` event (please provide the whole code).

```
case object PullCounter
case class PullResult(counter: Int)
case object PullFailed

class PullActor extends Actor {
  val period = 2.seconds
  var timerCancellable: Option[Cancellable] = None

  def scheduleTimer() = {
    timerCancellable = Some(
      context.system.scheduler.scheduleOnce(
        period, context.self, PullCounter
      )
    )
  }

  override def preStart() = scheduleTimer()

  // so we don't call preStart and schedule a new message
  // see http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.2.4/scala/howto.html
  override def postRestart(reason: Throwable) = {}

  def receive = LoggingReceive {
    case PullCounter =>
      val fReq = Database.fakeRequest()
      fReq.map(counter => PullResult(counter)) pipeTo self
      fReq.onFailure{ case _ => self ! PullFailed }

    case PullFailed =>
      scheduleTimer()

    case r: PullResult =>
      if(r.counter >= 5) {
        context.system.shutdown()
      } else {
        scheduleTimer()
      }
  }
}
```

I suppose, that example like above can help you (at least, it helped me with the similar situation). I took it from [this](http://eax.me/akka-scheduler/)

Comment: when I set the period in minute, like 5.minutes, it work fine for me.But If I set  it to 1.day, it failed.

Comment: @ mqshen what about something like this `val period = 24 hours` ?